# Laravel 5.1 - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, PDF file download not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have installed 'barryvdh/laravel-dompdf' using composer and added these lines

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class
'PDF'=>  Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class
```

to 'app.php' file in 'config' folder and also created  PdfController, like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App;
use PDF;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function invoice()
    {
        $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
        return $pdf->stream('testfile')
               ->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
    }
}
```

now the code works fine , contents are show  in browser in pdf format, but when i download this file, the file doesn't have any extension.I tried to modify the line containing return code like

```
return $pdf->stream('testfile.pdf')
                   ->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
```

But now, page directly provides file to download with name 'document.pdf'
which shows error while downloading,(dont konw how and from where this name 'document.pdf' came from).
Also i m working on localhost.

Comment: Try `$pdf->stream('testfile.pdf')` without `->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');` Probably dompdf sends the headers by itself

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but i have tried it already..& problem persists.. :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, after searching all over without results, I decided to play with the code and this worked for me.

Inside config/app.php

-> under providers add the line of code,

```
'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

[image]

-> under aliases add the line of code,

```
'PDF'       => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade' not 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

[image]

Mind the quotes and commas! Check the images above,

-> In your controller add the line of code,
use App;

[image]

Hopefully, you will be good to go....test using the lines of code..place them inside a method in your controller.

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

On success, your browser will open a PDF Viewer with a white PDF with the word Test

Cheers, enjoy your coding ;)

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to do with pdf ? To show in browser or to  download to disc?
this is example where pdf is downloaded

```
return $pdf->download('pdfName.pdf');
```

example from my code where i show notebook information in pdf

```
   $laptop = Notebook::findOrFail($id);
        $data['laptop'] = $laptop;
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.detaljiLaptop', $data);

        return $pdf->download($laptop->modelName.' Computers.pdf');
```

Comment: @SJBansod this code is actually working. I do this in the same way. What is the error or misbehaviour you get?

Comment: Thanks. i actually wanted to download the file., but it was also not working.,,i was using firefox with a bit old version..but when i tested it in different browser...(chrome), both codes( original code that i have posted in question  and other one of downloading pdf ) works fine...lesson: when using dompdf test it in different browser :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code  `view()->share($data);
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('sale.pdf');
        return $pdf->download('slip_out.pdf');`

instead of

```
return $pdf->stream('testfile.pdf')
               ->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
```