# how can i automatically download generated pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf

I  need to make my website automatically download the pdf that I generated it,
so I used this code to generate the pdf using dompdf :

```
include('pdf.php');
$file_name = "ORDER-".$name . '.pdf';
$html_code = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">';
$html_code .= fetch_customer_data();
$pdf = new Pdf();
$pdf->load_html($html_code);
$pdf->render();
$file = $pdf->output();
file_put_contents($file_name, $file);
```

when I run this in localhost the pdf downloaded in the same file where the source code file exists and everything is fine , but when I tried to run it on a real server I could not find the pdf so I used this code so it would be automatically downloaded in the downloads file :

```
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_name));
```

so this done the job but when I open the file I find it empty or with the result of the code source page 
I don't know what is wrong here can anyone tell me

the pdf.php file :

```
<?php

//pdf.php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class Pdf extends Dompdf{

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, PDF file download not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493647/laravel-5-1-barryvdh-laravel-dompdf-pdf-file-download-not-working-properly)

Comment: well it looks like  this is not working for me if  because I want to download  multiple pdfs

Answer (score 0):

I just added `return $pdf->stream();` and removed

```
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_name));
```